# Bootcamp Assistant - Startup disk cannot partion hard-drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, macbook-pro, boot-camp

MacBook is Mid 2014 Pro Retina on Mojave 10.14.1.

[image: Diskutil List]

[image: This is the error I'm talking about]

[image: As you can see more then enough free space available]

I've searched and searched but I can't seem to find a solution. Hopefully someone hear can help me

Comment: Check spotlight method in here https://mightytechno.com/not-enough-space-on-startup-disk-issue-in-bootcamp-assistance/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the start up disk is located in your disks listed but it has to be formatted Fat32 so that is more than likely your issue.